# Does calloc initialize structures arrays?

Tags: c, calloc

I have the doubt if calloc initialize  to zero all of the elements of a struct array like:

```
#define MAXDATA    10

struct Est2 {
int dato0;      // Index k
int dato1;      // Index j
int dato2;      // Index i
double dato3;   // Y Coordinate
};

Est2 *myArray = (Est2*) calloc(MAXDATA, sizeof(Est2));
```

I'm asking this because I don't want the initial data of myArray have garbage or Is there a problem if I don't initialize the array with any value if later in the code I will initialize it anyway for example storing the result of some arithmetical operations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you print the structure values to see their values are 0? To answer you question, yes calloc will initialize all elements to 0

Comment: `malloc` is the one that doesn't initialise the memory first, `calloc` sets it to value zero.

Comment: No, `calloc` set its to all bytes zero. This may or may not be value zero.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 5):

From `man calloc`:

```
void *calloc(size_t count, size_t size);
```

> The calloc() function contiguously allocates enough space for `count` objects that are `size` bytes of memory each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The allocated memory is filled with bytes of value zero.

`calloc()` guarantees that it's going to be pointing at zeroed data.

Answer (score 1):

All of the bytes in the structure are set to `0`.

This means that the `int`s have value `0`. The `double` could be a trap , although most common systems use IEEE 754 representation for `double`, in which the value would be `0.0`.

Comment: BTW, don't cast `calloc`.